# When handling a PCB, should I ground myself to earth or something else?

Tags: voltage, pcb, ground, esd

I have been researching electrostatic discharge when it comes to safely handling PCBs, and I'm having trouble understanding how I should ground myself. Many people say to just touch any conductive structure in your vicinity, but I don't understand how that would help. The way I understand it (and this could be wrong), as long as the PCB is at a different electrical potential to my body, current can flow. When the PCB arrives in the mail, it could be at a lower, higher, or the same potential as earth ground. If I ground myself to earth, there is no guarantee that the PCB will be at the same potential.

I have also seen people say to ground yourself to the thing you are working on - this usually comes up when people are talking about PC repair or construction. Even in this case, wouldn't grabbing a new PCB out of the bag run into the same problem (say if you were replacing a PCB in your computer)?

Comment: Depends on what’s populated on the PCB. Just wire-wound resistors or bare THz laser dies?

Comment: it's the easiest planet to ground yourself to...

Answer (score 1):

The most important thing is that you, and everything you touch, are at the same voltage.  So if you're installing a PCB into a metal case, then touching the case will help.

Proper anti-static workstations have a conductive rubber mat, which is grounded through a high resistance (about one megohm).  So if you connect a wrist strap to the mat, and place your case and PCB on the mat, then this provides a very effective anti-static environment.

Comment: Thanks for answering. I have a couple follow up questions/comments. First, I don't understand why touching the metal case you're installing the pcb into would help. Isn't it possible for there to be a voltage between the case and pcb before installation? Second, rubber isn't a conductor - I think it prevents tribocharging but I don't see how it helps the initial problem of there being a voltage between you and the pcb.

Comment: It is possible to make rubber be electrically conductive by doping it with large quantities of carbon black. Car tires are thermally and electrically conductive. Not like copper, of course. But they are conductive enough to avoid building up high ESD potential. There are other ways to make plastics somewhat conductive, but I don't know how they do it. I assume it is just a conductive additive.

Comment: @nat4311 As mkeith says, conductive rubber has added carbon black (soot).  It's still a poor conductor, but that doesn't matter.  A board inside an anti-static bag is unlikely to have much charge, as charges leak away over time.  In any case, it should equalise as you open the bag and touch the conductive surface of the bag.  The biggest static risk is people, as they keep walking around on insulating surfaces and generating static electricity.

Answer (score 1):

It is not my intention to be pedantic. But I want to clarify a point just to make sure we are talking about the same thing. A PCB is a printed circuit board. By convention, it is usually called a PCB when it has no parts on it. So it is not static sensitive and does not have any special handling requirements. Sometimes a PCB will also be called a "bare FAB." This is industry lingo.

After you put all the parts on it (this process is called "assembly") then it becomes a PCBA or PCB Assembly. Sometimes people do call a PCBA a PCB, but I am treating them as two separate things in my answer.

Once it is assembled, the PCBA should be stored and transported in an anti-static bag or other ESD safe packaging. You would only unpack the bag in a static safe location with anti-static mats and with proper grounding for you via a wrist strap etc. If you remove the PCBA from that location, you repackage it in static safe packaging.

If you are going to walk around with PCBA's which are not in static safe packaging and hand them from person to person, hold the board firmly in one hand making contact with GND and VCC and lots of other nets if possible. Don't let anyone come near the PCBA. If you hand the PCBA off to someone else, shake hands first or touch fingers or whatever with your other hand to equalize charge before transferring the PCBA. If you walk to a work bench to set it down, touch something grounded or put on a wrist strap before setting the board down. Even though a lot of people do this, it is not a best practice. For sure, if you are selling PCBA's to customers you absolutely should never be transporting them without static protective packaging.

Comment: "A PCB is a printed circuit board. By convention, it is usually called a PCB when it has no parts on it".  Not, that's not universal.  We usually call that a PWB, or Printed Wiring Board.  That's we get from the PWB vendor.

Comment: Thanks for answering. I still don't understand what shaking hands with the other person or touching something grounded does to help. To my knowledge, all this does is put you and the object you touched at the same charge. Before you touch it, the PCB could be at any other charge.

Comment: By equalizing person 1 to board then to person 2 ‘s finger , then there is no potential difference in transferring the board to person 2.  As I said with 0 CM voltage , no differential current can occur between floating personnel. Then by soft ground connection it is neutralized

Comment: You are only moderately conductive. By holding the PCBA firmly in such a way that your fingers are in contact with GND and other nets on the PCBA you and it are equalized, even if you slowly build up static charge due to walking or whatever. Then, when you get to another person and touch that person, it allows the two of you to equalize quickly. without passing the current through the PCBA or exposing it to a spark. After equalizing with the other person, it should be safe to pass the PCBA.

Answer (score 0):

When you handle any board by the ground tab you are making a common mode voltage so both are floating at the same potential but safely preventing a discharge to other nodes.

So when you touch a chassis or another person’s finger before transferring the board, you again are equalizing to the same common mode voltage for the floating ground, then transfer is safe afterwards. This can be accomplished with or without ground straps if you following this method.  But if you ignore these precautions then ground straps with 1M current limit in shoes to ESD work surface to gowns to to bench tops are necessary when people are less careful.

Comment: Thanks for answering. I am imagining a scenario in which a PCB arrives in the mail in an ESD bag and I have no clue what its current charge is. If I were to take it out of the bag and touch the ground pin, isn't there a risk that there is a voltage between my finger and the ground pin that could cause a high current to flow into the PCB?

Comment: How will the card return path exist by touching ground? How much charge did you expect the ESD bag to generate if you are touching it and the board ground?

Comment: If you have a good setup with an ESD mat and you are grounded with an ESD wrist strap, the bag will be equalized to the mat and to you just by you handling it to open it. By the time you open the bag, the board, bag, mat and you will all be at the same potential.